# Typical way for FAST small object detection on large images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

Say I have images of size 5400x3600 to 8200x5500px, I need to find a person there (typically 60px on a longer side). At the moment I use Yolov8-->onnx + SAHI library (which slices image into 640*640px with some overlay, typically 100-150 small images), but it doesn't give me the required speed.

With a yolo_v8-n(ano) I get 1.1 sec/image, with yolo_v8-x it is well above 6 s/image. I need it to be around 0.5 sec/image.

What is the typical (algorithmical) way to solve that problem?

Comment: the typical solution is to get better hardware. not joking. you say you have to search the entire picture and that a "nano" neural network already takes that much time.

Comment: on my 4090 inference takes 0.32 s per full image. The problem is that in the CV competition we are bound to use Tesla V100, which is ~4 times slower

Comment: find a cheaper model or find ways to not require inference on the entire picture or for every picture. be smart about the calculations you choose to perform.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NVIDIA gpu you can use TensorRT to optimize your model and run at much faster inference speed.

On the official repo of YoloV8 you can find an [example](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/examples/YOLOv8-ONNXRuntime/main.py) of inference using onnxruntime.

A quick way to use TensorRT is to change line 184 to:

```
session = ort.InferenceSession(self.onnx_model, providers=['TensorrtExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'])
```

This by the way will run the conversion (and optimization) from your onnx model to a TensorRT engine, each time you run the code.
I would suggest to do a separate export to a Trt engine and then simply load it for inference.

Consider that for a model like Yolo, depending on the GPU, it can take also 15 minutes to export it, so better to do it just one time.
Note that once you export the model to a TrT engine on a GPU, your engine will work only on that specific GPU model, so you need to export it again each time you change device.

For model export to Trt you can find a lot of resources online, i suggest you to do it with the tool [trtexec](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/master/samples/trtexec#building-trtexec).